# Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java

I am working on some project in java. 
Here I'm stuck at this problem and not able to figure out where I am going wrong.

I have made two classes: `Test` and `Child`.

When I run the code I am get a NullPointerException.

```
package com.test;
public class Test {

    child newchild = new child();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test().method();
    }
    void method() {
        String[] b;
        b = newchild.main();
        int i = 0;
        while (i < b.length) {
            System.out.println(b[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.test;
public class child {
    public String[] main() {
        String[] a = null;
        a[0] = "This";
        a[1] = "is";
        a[2] = "not";
        a[3] = "working";
        return a;
    }
}
```

Comment: In the future (and even now), you should clearly indicate which line is throwing the exception.  That information is available in the exception's stack trace.

Comment: ... it works as expected: it creates a `NullPointerException` in `child#main()` ;-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
String[] a = null;
a[0]="This";
```

You're immediately trying to dereference `a`, which is null, in order to set an element in it. You need to initialize the array:

```
String[] a = new String[4];
a[0]="This";
```

If you don't know how many elements your collection should have before you start populating it (and often even if you do) I would suggest using a `List` of some sort. For example:

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
a.add("This");
a.add("is");
a.add("not");
a.add("working");
return a;
```

Note that you have another problem here:

```
int i=0;
while(i<b.length)
    System.out.println(b[i]);
```

You're never changing `i`, so it will *always* be 0 - if you get into the `while` loop at all, you will never get out of it. You want something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println(b[i]);
}
```

Or better:

```
for (String value : b)
{
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

Comment: Gees Jon! You beat me already?

Answer (score 4):

This is the problem:

```
String[] a = null;
a[0]="This";
```

Answer (score 0):

They highlighted the problem of your probably the definition of null pointer exception would give you an idea what and where to find the problem in future. From java api doc, it defined what is npe and under what situation it will be thrown. Hope it help you.

Thrown when an application attempts to use null in a case where an object is required. These include:

```
* Calling the instance method of a null object.
* Accessing or modifying the field of a null object.
* Taking the length of null as if it were an array.
* Accessing or modifying the slots of null as if it were an array.
* Throwing null as if it were a Throwable value.
```

Answer (score 0):

package test;

public class Test {

```
child newchild = new child();

   public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Test().method();
    }
    void method()
    {
        String[] b;
        b = newchild.main();
        int i=0;
        while(i<b.length){
            System.out.println(b[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }
```

}

package test;

public class child {

```
public String[] main() {

    String[] a = {"This","is","not","Working"};
    return a;

}
```